# Lauching feh from python script over remote connection (pi zero w)

Tags: python, ssh, camera, headless, terminal

hoping someone might be able to help a complete newbie here. I am connected to a terminal session in my pi zero  via putty and Xming Server and have installed feh to inspect image files. so if I enter

```
sudo feh myimage.jpg
```

it launches a new x- window and shows the image perfectly over the remote connection on my laptop. So what I would like to do is have this run via a python script.

```
def displaylastimage():

    if not os.path.exists(cameraproperties.lastimage):
        print("file not found")
    else:
        lastimagefilecmd = str("feh "+ cameraproperties.lastimage)
        try:
        
            os.system(lastimagefilecmd)  #Try no1       
            os.system("DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"+lastimagefilecmd)   #Try no2
            image = subprocess.Popen(["feh", cameraproperties.lastimage])   # try no3
            subprocess.Popen(lastimagefilecmd, shell=True)     #try no 4 
        
        except Exception as Er:
            print(Er)
            print("something went wrong")
            pass
```

Every time I get the same error:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
```

I guessing that Feh is being called but the output is taking a different route when called from python? Any suggestions about how one might go about fixing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical, just when you ask a question, you get it to work. Following suggestions from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60088

> The problem appears to be that you are trying to connect an X client
> to the X display of a different user, and it does not have the correct
> authentication cookie.

I tried running the script without root privileges (no sudo) and it works fine. Still no idea why but I guess as was suggested in the other form, something to do with x client - x display and python! If anyone wants to explain this to me I would be delighted to learn.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.